# What is causing this horrible grinding noise?

Tags: grinding

My vehicle STOPS grinding after driving through water.
Once dried it grinds constantly.  I drive every single day and have notice each time it's dry out the grinding is worse and worse ,but is completely silent each time it's wet out .

Comment: Have you tried figuring out where the grinding noise is coming from? E.g. Engine Bay, Rear Right/Left, Construction Site? Also what do you mean wet out? as in the underbody of the car is getting wet?

Comment: When the underbody is wet from driving in the rain through puddles. The noise is coming from the drivers side. It isn't under the hood it sounds like its by the tire.

Comment: The brake pads look fine. Not sure what it is.